# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification

Tags: docker, google-cloud-automl

I'm currently following this tutorial to run a model on Docker that was built using the Google Cloud AutoML Vision:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial

I'm having trouble running the container, specifically running this command:

`sudo docker run --rm --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} -p ${PORT}:8501 -v ${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}:/tmp/mounted_model/0001 -t ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}`

I have my environment variables set up right (did an `echo $<env_var>`). I do not have a /tmp/mounted_model/0001 directory on my local system. My model path is configured to be the model location on the cloud storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}` must be a directory on the host on which you're running the container.

Your question suggests that you're using the Cloud Storage bucket path but you cannot do this.

Reviewing the tutorial, I think the instructions are confusing.

You are told to:

```sh
gsutil cp \
  ${YOUR_MODEL_PATH} \
  ${YOUR_LOCAL_MODEL_PATH}/saved_model.pb
```

So, your command should probably be:

```sh
sudo docker run \
  --rm \
  --interactive --tty \
  --name=${CONTAINER_NAME} \
  --publish=${PORT}:8501 \
  --volume=${YOUR_LOCAL_MODEL_PATH}:/tmp/mounted_model/0001 \
  ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}
```

**NB** I added `--interactive --tty` to make debugging easier; it's optional

**NB** `${YOUR_LOCAL_MODEL_PATH}` not `${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}`

**NB** The command should not be `-t ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}` omit the `-t`

I've not run through this tutorial.

Comment: I got it working in the end, apparently the script later in the tutorial doesn't work if I used the --publish flag (error was: Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/models/default:predict), so instead I did a "-p 8501:8501". Thanks for the help.